# Equity vs stock options (startup)

Tags: salary, hiring-process, startup, equity

- Is there any significant disadvantage receiving stock options vs.
  shares in a new startup?
- What could be the excuses for not giving shares but stock options and
  would it be reasonable to insist on shares?

**Background:** I may be joining a fresh but fully funded (pre series A) startup. I would be employee #5. I would be fully committed and invest 100% of time. Hence I would expect equity (like 0.5%-1%?) but I think I heard somebody talking about stock options. The latter would not motivate me too much to work in a startup but that's just a feeling so I wonder if there are actual disadvantages of stock options vs. equity.

Comment: Maybe your question would be better received if you tried to reword your question towards something like "How can I ask for equity rather than stock options"

Comment: This question might be better suited at [money.se].

Comment: This is better suited questions for  personal finance SE as mentioned above. Just a short example: If your company's stock worth $4 and you own 100 of them, you own $400 of asset. If you only own 500 options to buy at $5, you own $0 of asset.

Comment: For such an important decision, I would urge you to read the vast amount of info on the www, just google:  https://www.forbes.com/sites/allbusiness/2016/02/27/how-employee-stock-options-work-in-startup-companies/  here's a basic intro: https://www.allbusiness.com/how-employee-stock-options-work-in-startup-companies-103450-1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All else being equal options are BETTER than actual stock (at least in the US)

If you get stock, you have to pay income tax on the value of the stock when it vests, regardless of whether you can sell the stock or not.

With option, you don't own anything unless you exercise and no tax is due unless you either exercise or sell (depending type of stock options and AMT or not).

Taxation of these things is horribly complicated and options give you the same earning potential but more control over timing and tax mitigation.

Comment: @Ramhound: correct, but stock is worth this way. Not only do you not get anything, you pay income tax on money you never made. Stock options are at least zero.